# Is there a nicer way of iteration and comparing objects in 2 arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, angular10

I am still fresh in JS/Angular, and maybe I dont know about something. I am having 2 arrays: : `boardP1: BoardCellModel[][]` and `forbiddenCells: BoardCellModel[]`. And I want to know, if in the first array there are cells matching cells in 2nd array. In C# there is `LINQ` for this. Is there anything similar in JS? For now my code looks like this:

```
private compareBoardWithForbiddenCells(
    forbiddenCells: Array<BoardCellModel>
  ): boolean {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        for (let f = 0; f < forbiddenCells.length; f++) {
          if (
            this.boardP1[i][j].col == forbiddenCells[f].col &&
            this.boardP1[i][j].row == forbiddenCells[f].row &&
            this.boardP1[i][j].value == 1
          ) {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
```

Is there a better way to write this code?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand, are you trying to find matching x,y from two 2-dimentional arrays? And also, how would you use `LINQ` for this? There are array functions in javascript like `map`, `reduce`, `sort` that are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a `Set` for all forbidden coordinates and check the value in advance.

```js
const
    forbidden = new Set,
    key = (...a) => a.join('|');

for (const { col, row } of forbiddenCells) forbidden.add(key(col, row));

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if (this.boardP1[i][j].value !== 1) continue;
        if (forbidden.has(key(this.boardP1[i][j].col, this.boardP1[i][j].row))) return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code in order to achieve your goal, right now i have 2 arrays, names, lastNames, i will match both with the identifier (id)

```js
let names = [{ id: 1, name: 'John' }, { id: 2, name: 'Jane' }, { id: 3, name: 'Oliver' }, { id: 4, name: 'Barry'}];
let lastNames = [{ id: 1, lastName: 'Doe'}, { id: 2, lastName: 'Abc'}, { id: 3, lastName: 'Queen'}, { id: 4, lastName: 'Allen' }]

names.forEach(item => item.lastName = lastNames.find(lname => item.id === lname.id).lastName);

console.log(names);
```

Check working
[code here](https://jsfiddle.net/czda4w96/)

Comment: But you dont have `lastName` prop on `names`.